# How to reliably "PrintScreen" (save screen contents) over an RDP connection?

Tags: c#

I've made a simple PrintScreen method that i use when my automated tests failes. This is just so i can email the error and a printscreen of the screen at that moment of the error.
This is how the code for PrintScreen.Save() looks like.

```
public static class PrintScreen
{
    public static string Save(string fileName)
    {
        var printScreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printScreen);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printScreen.Size);
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            File.Delete(fileName);
        printScreen.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

The method works fine when i run tests on my computer. But we use another computer for the scheduled automated tests. And i connect to it through RDP (the automated tests need inteaction with the desktop, it can't be runned while computer is locked.) This is my problem. Sometimes the printscreen is not taking the screen.

**So my question is this** : Is there any other way in writing a "better" method or is there something wrong in my current method?. Any suggestions is welcome.

My investigation concludes this.

- Screensaver or simular inactivated.
- It works perfectly running on my local machine.
- When i have debugged it everything works out nicely.
- The remote computer does only have one screen.

Could there be any error from the save to file that i'm missing?

Best Regards 
Jonas

Comment: "Sometimes the printscreen is not taking the screen" means you get an error, you get a blank image ... ?

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep` already looks suspect (aside from any current issues you're experiencing) - why is it there?

Comment: @Alex the output in the file is empty or the file dosn't exists.

Comment: @Damien I don't know if i need it actuallt, the save will return when it's done i persume. So i removed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorry to bother you guys with this issue.. But there wasn't any concrete errors in the code.
It turns out to be the AntiVirus program that was removing some of this files, some but not everyone. And my virusprogram on my local computer isn't the same.
I've now managed to add my process as a secure process and now i think it works. I've tried it out a few times and it works much better.

Thanks for the responses, they made me think about my code a bit furter, and sorry for taking your time.
//Jonas

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a bit of [Rubber ducking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).